# How do I manage my company's interactions with a company I interviewed with?

Tags: interviewing, management

At some point in the past I considered leaving my job for a different job at a non-competing company. The interview went well, but I decided not to take the job. My boss doesn't know I considered leaving.

Now I've been promoted to a position where I may need to manage my company's interactions with the company I interviewed with. I'm concerned my boss may not take well to the information that I considered leaving. But if we interact with that company I can't guarantee he won't find out. What is the proper way of handling this situation?

Comment: Presumably the other party has enough professionalism to keep their comments to a minimal "we've met" or even to simply not mention that they know you? It's not that hard to figure out that you don't want your boss to know you've interviewed with them...

Comment: Your concerned your boss will find out you looked at other quality companies, and they liked you, and you still chose to stay? My boss would be glad to know his employees are the cream of the crop.

Comment: @corsiKa Humans are unpredictable.

Comment: Another way it could possibly be a good thing they find out is if it prompts discussion on why you were previously considering leaving, which may lead to improvements that make you want to stay even more.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The proper way of handling this situation is to leave it alone. The company you interviewed with likely understands the importance of confidentiality in these matters.

In the unlikely event that your interview is mentioned, you have a great response -- the other company made a great offer but you decided to stay, because you are a loyal employee who has been recognized and rewarded for your excellent work.